# Insert a new key value pair at a particular position in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of small dictionaries, and i want to insert a value `build_time` into each of the dictionaries where `build_time` is different for different `job_name` in the dictionary.

I have appending to the list of dictionaries already created in one of the functions in my code but my code just appends all the values at the end of the dictionary list.
This is what i have tried so far

```
part of code
# call the function to create initial dictionary
   url = "https://" + self.jenkins_instance + "/api/json?pretty=true&tree=jobs[name,lastBuild[url,id,building,builtOn,timestamp,result]]"
        try:
            urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)
            res = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.user,
                                                    self.jenkins_api),
                                verify=False)
            jobs = json.loads(res.text).get("jobs")
            for j in jobs:
                last_build = j.get("lastBuild")
                if last_build is None:
                    continue
                self.start_timestamp = last_build.get("timestamp")

    records = {"last_build": self.start_timestamp}
    self.my_list.append(records)
    print(self.my_list)
```

Here is my initial list

```
[{'job_name': 'name`', 'job_state': 'state_old'},
{'job_name': 'name2', 'job_state': 'state_new'}, 
{'job_name': 'name3', 'job_state': 'state_old'}]
```

This is a sample list, the actual list is much longer.

This is what the expected output is

```
[{'job_name': 'name`', 'job_state': 'state_old', 'build_time':'xx-xx-xxx'}
,{'job_name': 'name2', 'job_state': 'state_new', 'build_time':'xy-xx-xxxy'}
,{'job_name': 'name3', 'job_state': 'state_old','build_time':'xx-xx-zzz'}]
```

What my code does is  this

```
[{'job_name': 'name`', 'job_state': 'state_old'}
,{'job_name': 'name2', 'job_state': 'state_new'}
,{'job_name': 'name3', 'job_state': 'state_old'}
, {'build_time':'xx-xx-xxx'}
,{'build_time':'xy-xx-xxxy'}
, 'build_time':'xx-xx-zzz'}]
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to add the 'build_time' section to the dictionary? It would be a lot easier to dissect.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: Format your jsons so they are fully visible without annoying scrolling

Comment: You need to make a [MCVE]. And like @Marcin said, it would be better if we didn't have to scroll to read the dicts; `pprint.pprint` could help with that.

Comment: Done, sorry about the confusion

Comment: valid json uses `"` not `'` for quotation

Comment: this is the dictionary data that i have pasted, list of dictionaries actually..i am building the dictionary as of now, i can build the desired format from it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update every single dictionary in the list, change this:

```
self.my_list.append(records)
```

To this:

```
for item in self.my_list:
    item.update(records)
```